# How do I save user input permenantly?

Tags: java, input, save, output, extend

So I have created an Account class and i wanted to save the user details permenantly for future use. For example, should the user create an account, i would like him/her to be able to use his info including balance in the future. 
Please help me!

```
package mini_project;

import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Account {

private String firstName, surname;
private short transactionNumber;
String input;
private int startingAmount;

public Account(String first, String sur, int amount){

    firstName = first;
    surname = sur;
    startingAmount = amount;
}

public void setFirstName (){

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What Is Your First  Name?").toUpperCase();
    firstName = input;
}

public String getFirstName (){

    return firstName;
}

public void setSurname (){

input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What Is Your  Surname?").toUpperCase   ();
    surname = input;
}

public String getSurname (){

    return surname;
}

public void setTransactionNumber (){

    Random rand = new Random ();
    int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(1000)+1;
    transactionNumber = (short) randomNumber;
}

public short getTransactionNumber(){

    return transactionNumber;
}

public void setShares(){

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How Many Shares Do You Currently Own?");
    startingAmount = Integer.parseInt(input);
}

public int getShares(){

    return startingAmount;
}
}
```

Comment: You probably want to have a database to store your users. If you really can't use a database you could serialize your Account objects to binary files but that is not a very good/scalable solution

Comment: can you show me the code on how i could do this?

Comment: @ShannonDavidson This is a useful example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Comment: If you want to serialize your objects check out this [java tutorial on serializing objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) you would need to make sure you have a certain format for your file names so you can easily deserialize your objects when needed. Again serialization is not the preferable option over a database. You will need to learn sql for that though (it's a super useful skill to know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always make the account class implement Serializable. This will allow you to save and import the object's instance, in this case individual account objects. These instances can be saved into a text file. They can also be encrypted if your program requires more security.

Comment: No problem @ShannonDavidson

Answer (score -2):

If you want to save the data permanently, You need to use database.
You can make your instance variable static. It will save permanently unless you close the program.

```
private static String firstName, surname;
private static short transactionNumber;
private static int startingAmount;
```

Then get the setters and getters. But remove the static word in the functions of setters and getters. You only need static in an instance variable.

Comment: Thanks slightly helpful, i wish there was a way java would allow you to save entries into a text file and be able to read from that textfile

Comment: You can... you just have to write it yourself